What will going near the speed of light would look like?
Person A travels in a train with a constant velocity close to the speed of light and is in motion relative to a bystander B. As of my understanding, person B will perceive person A's clock to move in slow-motion (in person B's frame of reference) and in the same way person A will perceive person B's clock to move in slow-motion (in person A's frame of reference). They will both in their own frame of references see their own clocks to move "normally". In the first case (where B believes A to be in motion), if time dilation is supposed to make person A move slowly (from B's frame of reference), will B just see an almost stationary picture of person A and the train? If it appears to be moving slowly, how long does it stay like that? I have some trouble understanding what person B will see. I am mainly interested in the aspect of time dilation and not other distortions caused by moving near the speed of light.

Is A moving toward or away from B?

What you need to do is draw the spacetime diagram for the stationary observer then perform a Lorentz transform and draw the spacetime diagram for the other observer.

What they see is not the same as what they measure, because of the time delays due to the finite speed of light.

If A is moving toward B, he will see B's clock ticking in "fast forward", but will realize this is partly because B keeps getting closer, so light from each tick of B's clock arrives faster than light from the previous tick.  After correcting for this, he will conclude that B's clock is ticking slowly.
If A is moving away from B, he will see B's clock ticking in slow motion, but will realize this is partly because B keeps getting farther, so light from each tick of B's clock takes longer to arrive than light from the previous tick.  After correcting for this, he will conclude that B's clock is ticking slowly, but not as slowly as it appears.
If A moves away from B while A' moves toward B, both at the same speed, then, after making their corrections, they will agree on the (slow) tick rate of B's clock.

If you really mean 'see', as in experience in real time with their eyes, then they won't see anything. If I pass you at the speed of light, I will be   at an easily visible distance for too short a period of time for your mind to register. Suppose I fire a bullet past you- you won't see it, and the bullet moves at a tiny faction of the speed of light.
If instead, by 'see' you mean what happens, regardless of whether individuals can see it or not, then what happens is that time in A's frame is out of synch with time in B's frame. If for example, there was a huge line of clocks and cameras in each frame, and if at exactly twelve o'clock in B's frame all the cameras in B's frame took a snapshot of the closest passing clock in A's frame, then only one of the clocks in A's frame would show exactly 12 O'clock- in one direction from that clock, all the other clocks in A's frame would show progressively later times, and in the other direction they would show progressively earlier times.
From B's perspective, all the clocks in A's frame, along the direction of motion between the two frames, are out of synch. A conversely thinks all the clocks in B's frame are out of synch.
That's how time dilation happens. If you walk past a series of clocks that are out of synch- say each one is a second ahead of the next- your watch will seem to be running slow, because you will think it is losing a second compered with each clock you pass. That's time dilation. In fact, your watch and the clocks are all ticking at the same rate- it is the lack of synchronisation that gives the effect.
The key point is that time dilation never involves comparing one clock in one frame directly with one clock in another.

The situation becomes clear if we note how the clocks would be compared. One way is to have one clock per wagon in the train, all of them synchronized in the train's frame.
The bystander would always compare its own clock with the clock in the wagon momentarily in front of B. What would happen according to SR is that the succession of clocks in the train would show a progressively dilated time, compared with B clock. They are synchronized in A frame, but not in the B frame.
But the experience could be made in the opposite way. Several clocks in the platform, synchronized in the ground frame. And one clock A at one of the wagons, comparing with the clock in the platform momentarily in front of A. Now, A would see the clocks in the platform progressively showing a dilated time. They are synchronized in B frame, but not in the A frame.

Let's get rid of the issue of moving towards or moving away by saying that A is traveling in a circle around B and B is rotating to keep a constant eye on A. And then we'll say that A is a long distance away, perhaps the distance from the Earth to the Sun, so he is not moving too fast to be seen. And B has a really good telescope.
Before this experiment, they both agree that A will wave his hand once per second.
So the answer to your question is that B we'll see A waving his hand much slower than once per second. As A gets closer and closer to the speed of light B we'll see the hand moving even slower and slower until it nearly stops.


In the first case (where B believes A to be in motion), if time
dilation is supposed to make person A move slowly (from B's frame of
reference), will B just see an almost stationary picture of person A
and the train?

If person $\text{A}$ on the train is going from left to right at $0.8c$ relative to $\text{B}$, then $\text{B}$ will not see the train moving slowly from left to right. $\text{B}$ will simply see the train moving at $0.8c$. If there is a flashing light on the train that is flashing once per second from $\text{A}$'s point of view, then $\text{B}$ will see this light flashing faster at $3$ times per second when the train is coming towards $\text{B}$ and flashing slower at once every $3 \ \text{seconds}$ when the train is going away. This is partly due to Newtonian Doppler effect. When the classical Doppler effect is taken into account, $\text{B}$ will calculate that the light is flashing slower at a rate of one flash per $1.66 \ \text{seconds}$. This is the time dilation. The classical Doppler effect is one of the visual distortions that have to be removed to find the real-time dilation effect. Everything in $\text{A}$'s rest frame on board the train appears to be happening in slow motion by $\text{B}$'s calculations, and any clocks on board will appear to be ticking slower, but the train itself will appear to be moving normally fast.
If $\text{A}$ decided to fire a relativistic gun towards the front of the train that fires bullets at $0.9c$ in the rest frame of the gun, $B$ would measure the bullet to be moving slowly away from $\text{A}$ at less than $0.2c$ because no observer sees the bullet moving at greater than $c$ relative to themselves. The velocity of the bullet relative to $\text{B}$ is just under $0.99c$. This is a property of relativistic velocity addition. If $\text{A}$ fires the gun towards the back of the train, $\text{B}$ will measure the bullet as moving at $-0.36c$ relative to themselves.
In relativity, it is important to note that what an observer actually 'sees' may differ from the theoretical time dilation expectations due to light travel times, and the Doppler effect described above is an example of this.
Trigger Warning: The following is controversial.
Above, I said things inside the train appear to move in slow motion according to $\text{B}$'s calculations, but when I considered what happens if $\text{A}$ drops something inside the train, there appears to be an exception.
We know from the equivalence principle that a horizontally moving object always drops at $9.8 \ \text{m/s}^2$ from the point of view of someone standing on the Earth, no matter how fast it moves horizontally relative to the surface of the Earth, with no exceptions, even if it is a photon. $\text{B}$ will see the object dropped by $\text{A}$ as falling with the normal acceleration of gravity. Starting with the equation of motion, $$\Delta x = \frac{1}{2} \ a (\Delta t)^2 \iff \Delta t = \sqrt{2 \frac{\Delta x}{a}},$$ to $\text{B}$ it takes $\sqrt{2\times 1.8/9.8} \approx 0.6060 \ \text{s}$ for the object to fall $1.8 \ \text{m}$. To $\text{B}$, objects dropped in $\text{A}$'s reference frame do not fall in slow motion.
Inside the train, $\text{A}$'s clock is running slowly. By $\text{A}$'s measurement, the object takes $$t' = \gamma \Delta t \approx \sqrt{1-0.8^2} \times 0.6060 \approx 0.3636 \ \text{s}$$ to fall, where $\gamma$ is the usual relativistic gamma factor. This makes the acceleration of the falling object $$a' \approx 2 \frac{\Delta x}{(\Delta t')^2} \approx 2\times \frac{1.8}{0.3636^2} \approx 27.23 \ \text{m/s}^2,$$ by $\text{A}$'s measurements. The acceleration of gravity appears about $3$ times faster than normal to $\text{A}$. While it is normally said that $\text{A}$ does not notice anything usual due to time dilation because everything is slower by the same amount in his reference frame, this is apparently not true when observing falling objects when moving in a gravitational field. We cannot attribute this difference to gravitational time dilation. $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ are subject to the same gravitational time dilation. The time dilation due to the gravitational field of the Earth is tiny in this context and is negligible relative to the large effect calculated here. The situation is not symmetric when there is even a small gravitational field present.

The situation is symmetric. A sees B's clock tick slower, and B sees A's clock tick slower. At very nearly the speed of light that time dilation will make each person appear to be not flowing through time from the perspective of the other - in both directions as well. It'll still seem to be that way until the train slows down or the "stationary" observer gets on another relativistic train.
The key aspect here is that A being on a 299,792 km/s train and B sitting on the sidewalk is no different from the reverse - neither reference frame is preferred.

Downvoted for "time dilation will make each person appear to be not flowing through time from the perspective of the other" which could mean any of several things, all of which are wrong.

Now this is not true.If that were true the twin paradox would be unsolvable.
